# railsでいいね機能を付けたのですがうまくいいねが追加されません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

記事の一覧からいいねをクリックするとこのようなエラーが出てしまいます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

@postには記事のIDが入っていてそれを現在のユーザーのfavoritesにしまうと思うのですが@favoritesというインスタンス変数がいまいちわかりません。このbuildを使うと@favoriteの中に現在のユーザーのお気に入りのポストという感じに作られるイメージなのですが合っているでしょうか？
このコードで動くはずなのですがrailsを始めたばかりなのでイメージが薄くエラーが取れないです。助けて下さいお願いします。

追記：

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/index'

  get 'users/show'

  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do
    get :favorites, on: :member
  end
  resources :posts do
    resources :favorites, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
  root 'posts#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

favorite.rb

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
    class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
        belongs_to :post
    end
    #追記2：以下のuserとpostのpresenceをコメントアウトしたらうまく動いたのですが
    #userとpostが空でエラーが出ていたみたいなのですが空でいいのでしょうか?
    validates :user, presence: true
    validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :post_id }
    validates :post, presence: true
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
    acts_as_ordered_taggable_on :interests
    has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
    def favorited_by? user
        favorites.where(user_id: user.id).exists?
    end
 end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :posts
  has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
end
```

favorites_controller.rb
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        #追記1：以下のpost:とpost_id:に変更したら上の画像の別のエラーが出ました。
        @favorite = current_user.favorites.build(post_id: @post)

        if @favorite.save
          redirect_to posts_url, notice: "お気に入りに登録しました"
        else
          redirect_to posts_url, alert: "この投稿はお気に入りに登録できません"
        end
     end

    def destroy
        @favorite = current_user.favorites.find_by!(post_id: params[:post_id])
        @favorite.destroy
        redirect_to posts_url, notice: "お気に入りを解除しました"
    end

end
```

favoriteテーブル

```
class CreateFavorites < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :favorites do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :post_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コードからRuby on Rails 5、Deviseを使っていると推定して回答します。
このような前提条件は基本的に明記してください。

---

> @postには記事のIDが入っていてそれを現在のユーザーのfavoritesにしまうと思うのですが@favoritesというインスタンス変数がいまいちわかりません。このbuildを使うと@favoriteの中に現在のユーザーのお気に入りのポストという感じに作られるイメージなのですが合っているでしょうか？

`@post`はPostのidではなくPostオブジェクトが入るコードになっています。
`@favorite`の理解は概ね合っています。`current_user.favorites.build(..)`は新たにFavoriteオブジェクトを生成したのち、favorite.userにcurrent_userを結びつけます。

---

エラーの「unknown attribute: 'post' for Favorite.」はFavoriteにpostという属性が見つからないことを示しています。
また、`@favorite.save`で「undefined method `user` for #<Favorite:0xa520ecc>」は`user`メソッドがFavoriteオブジェクトに見当たらないことを示しています。
これらは、FavoriteモデルにPostやUserのリレーションが無いということです。
そこで最初に疑うべき箇所はFavoriteモデルのコード app/models/favorite.rb です。

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
    class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
        belongs_to :post
    end
    #...
end
```

これは明らかにおかしいです。

1. FavoriteモデルにUserとPostのリレーションを含む別のFavoriteモデルが内包してしまっています。通常はこのような構造にはなりません。（内側のモデルクラスは`Favorite::Favorite`になるため別物です）
2. `ActiveRecord::Base`はRuby on Rails 4以下で使われていた`ApplicationRecord`相当（正確には継承元）のクラスです。5以上では使わないでください。

以上を踏まえると次のように修正されます。

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :post

    validates :user, presence: true
    validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :post_id }
    validates :post, presence: true
end
```